# Function changes outside variable unprompted

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple Minimax algorithm for playing tic-tac-toe. A function `make_move()` takes a board and x/y coordinates and returns the board with the given move made. I use this function both to make moves and create a list of child boards to choose the best next move.

My problem: Any time I call the function, it changes the global `board` variable to reflect the move as well. I don't use `board = make_move()` and have also tried using the function with a copy of `board` instead, to no effect. Here is a simpler version of my code:

```
board = [ [0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3) ] # [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

def make_move(state, x, y): # return board with given move made
  state[y][x] = 1

  return state

print(make_move(board, 1, 1)) # prints [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

print(board) # also prints [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

My question: since I don't specify `board = make_move(board, ...)`, which would obviously change the original `board` variable, what am I doing wrong here which causes `board` to change?

Passing `board[:]` instead of `board` to make_move(), which should otherwise create a seperate copy, does not work.

I hope this was descriptive enough; it's my first question :)

Comment: Consider this.  In the top line, you create one list object that contains three other list objects.  In your entire program, those are the ONLY four list objects that ever exist.  Those lists go by different names, `state` and `board` both refer to that original list object.

Comment: The global variable `board` is not changed, it is still referring to the exact same object, the on you passed to `make_move`, and mutate inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[:] is creating so called shallow copy- a new object with references copied from the old one. To create a deep copy use `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
import copy
board = [ [0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3) ] # [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

def make_move(state, x, y): # return board with given move made
  state_copy = copy.deepcopy(state)
  state_copy[y][x] = 1

  return state_copy
```